# Boost requirements in terms of C++ language version and Standard Library dependencies

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, embedded

After much research and digging into the Boost libraries documentation, I cannot find answers or high-level advice on the following questions:

- Which are the requirements of Boost regarding the C++ language version? C++03? C++11? How can I now which version of Boost requires which version of the C++ language?

  - Does it depends on the specific library (most of the times, the .hpp file included).
  - Do I have to check manually (as a last resort) with all the libraries I may need and all the versions of Boost, from the latest and then moving backwards in case I need a less strict dependency?
- Which are the dependencies with the C++ Standard Library?

Context:

- I am evaluating the use of Boost on an embedded platform (MCU with limited and no virtual memory, no underlying OS).
- I have GCC 4.8.1 with C++11 support.
- We *do not* have a complete C++ Standard Library for this platform.
- I was hoping to use Boost as a complement and substitute of the C++ Standard Library, hence my research on the topics asked above.

I appreciate the high quality of the Boost project documentation, however, I could not find any reference to the above topics in the official documentation. Maybe I have missed something.

P.S.: A gente introduction to the historically complex topic of C++ language versions, Standard Library and Boost libraries,

http://news.dice.com/2013/03/15/comparing-the-c-standard-and-boost-2/

Comment: Yes, you do always test your software on all the platforms you require. And then there is http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/msm/doc/HTML/ch04s03.html

Comment: I know about regression testing. However, that doesn't address the core of my concers.

Answer (score 1):

http://beta.boost.org/development/tests/master/developer/summary.html

This lists some of the platforms boost is tested against.
Every release, boost mentions which platforms it has been tested against.

It is expected to work on more platforms than those listed, but there are no guarantees.

Comment: Thanks for the link, however, that doesn't answer my questions :-( The link simply shows the test coverage for the different compilers, options and platforms, for the different Boost libraries. What what about minimum set of dependencies? Which C++ language version (minimum) do I require? Which language features? Do I need a partial/full Standard Library?

Answer (score 0):

The support and evolution of a boost library in terms of supporting new c++ features is not tightly related to the other libraries. Since boost has been living mainly in a mono standard world (c++03), it was implied that it works in c++03. But as boost people tend to do stuff in a smart way, for the libraries who now support c++11 features, they either use some feature emulation system to keep it working on c++03 or they test for your configuration and if you can't use some advanced stuff then they just disable it.

So basically there is no language standard requirements, it works on all c++03/C++11/C++14 with different features sets.

For other requirements (namely parts of the STL) it directly depends on the libraries you want.  The best way is to test. You might find a way to launch their unit test on your plateforme to see how much is working.

You might also want to check [Boost Config](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/config/doc/html/index.html) which is the library that all others use to check for features.